# Live Streaming with Wordpress?

Tags: plugins

Does anyone know a working set up for a live streaming event delivered by a wordpress page? There should be 500 participants. I have no idea, what I need to consider and which technological set up neccessary to do this. YouTube / Zoom is not an option, because the event should be delivered on an excklusive page with restricted accesss …

Best and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/), it’s open source and can be embedded/integrated as you require for member areas etc. Here’s an [example plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webinar-and-video-conference-with-jitsi-meet/) that uses it.

I have no affiliation with Jitsi or the plugin.